# Running TypeSafe reactive-microservices example give error: Requesting ticker failed because Received fatal alert

Tags: typesafe, typesafe-stack

I am trying to run the [reactive-microservices](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/reactive-microservices) example provided on TypeSafe website.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I ran `sudo docker-compose up` in one terminal window. It was successful.

And then in another terminal window I ran `sbt runAll`. It gives me the following warning and is stuck on it.

```
[WARN] [02/14/2016 00:21:25.826] [btc-users-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.tcp://btc-users@127.0.0.1:2551/user/$b] Requesting ticker failed because Received fatal alert: internal_error to https://market.bitbay.pl/API/Public/BTCUSD/ticker.json
```

What is this and how do I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score -1):

In Data Fecther I changed the URL

from:   //private val url = "https://market.bitbay.pl/API/Public/BTCUSD/ticker.json"

to:      private val url = "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTCUSD/ticker.json"

and now it works...

[info] [DEBUG] [03/23/2016 11:36:45.875] [btc-users-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.tcp://btc-users@127.0.0.1:2551/user/$b] Broadcasting ticker Ticker(430,430,430,387.01,429.99,414.83,430,0.1602558)
[info] [DEBUG] [03/23/2016 11:36:46.917] [btc-users-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.tcp://btc-users@127.0.0.1:2551/user/$b] Broadcasting ticker Ticker(430,430,430,387.01,429.99,414.83,430,0.1602558)
[info] [DEBUG] [03/23/2016 11:36:47.925] [btc-users-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] [akka.tcp://btc-users@127.0.0.1:2551/user/$b] Broadcasting ticker Ticker(430,430,430,387.01,429.99,414.83,430,0.1602558)
[info] [DEBUG] [03/23/2016 11:36:48.947] [btc-users-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.tcp://btc-users@127.0.0.1:2551/user/$b] Broadcasting ticker Ticker(430,430,430,387.01,429.99,414.83,430,0.1602558)